# jquery colorbox close on HTML "Download Now" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The jquery colorbox is working but I'd like to close it when a user clicks the "Download Now" HTML

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $( document ).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$('#cboxLoadedContent').show()}, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){$('#overlay_full').show()}, 5000);
    });

    function close_pop_up()
    {
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').hide('slow');
        $('#overlay_full').hide('slow');
    }



      (function() {
        var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
        sa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://cdn' : 'http://cdn') + '.ywxi.net/js/1.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
      })();
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<a class="download_btn large" href="http://example.com"     title="Download">Download Now <img class="bd_arrow" src="images/btn_arrow.png" /></a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `click` listener to the link that will call the `close_pop_up` function that already exists.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#cboxLoadedContent').show()}, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#overlay_full').show()}, 5000);
    // New code here
    $('.download_btn').on('click', close_pop_up);
});
```